# Sorting analysis column based on selection from dashboard prompt

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have got a dashboard prompt with a couple of radio-buttoned fields, say Name, Employee No. and DOB. I need to select one of the field and the resultant analysis to be sorted based on my selection.

So if I select 'Name', my analysis would be sorted by the 'Name' column.

Answer (score 0):

This is a questionable requirement at best since you are trying to build a complex solution that's pretty pointless:

For every tabular analysis view you can click on the column header and sort on whatever you want.

For graphical views you can right-click and sort on whatever you want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pq2Z.jpg

Comment: Thanks for response. And yeah i know about clicking on the column header for sorting. Just wanted to know if there is a way to achieve it via dashboard prompt.

Comment: Yes, but it would be wasteful and overcomplicated.